# WordPress - Yoast Disable specific page href link in breadcrumb trail, but don't remove text

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs, yoast

Using Yoast to generate the breadcrumb trail, I can't figure out how to remove just the HREF attribute, so the breadcrumb is just text.  I'm using custom links to organize the site content.  I put in blank pages so that the breadcrumb trail would render properly, but now of course I have a link to blank pages.  I've considered putting an index/TOC on these pages, but it seems so pointless.

Here's the simplest code that I've found that disables link and text, but I can't find an example (that works) that removes just the link (href).

```
 add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_single_link' ,'wpseo_remove_breadcrumb_link', 10 ,2);

function wpseo_remove_breadcrumb_link( $link_output , $link ){
    $text_to_remove = 'Products';
  
    if( $link['text'] == $text_to_remove ) {
      $link_output = '';
    }
 
    return $link_output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_single_link' ,'wpseo_just_remove_breadcrumb_link', 10 ,2);
function wpseo_just_remove_breadcrumb_link( $link_output , $link ){
    //In case you want to remove multiple links put those texts here in this array.
    $text_to_remove = ['Products', 'Something else']; 
    if(in_array($link['text'] , $text_to_remove )) {
        $link_output = str_replace('href="'.$link['url'].'"' , "" , $link_output);
        return str_replace('data-wpel-link="internal"' , "" , $link_output);
    }
    return $link_output;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad its working for you. Do accept the answer by clicking checkmark so that others looking out for same issue can benefit out of it.